# Dialogbox with no separator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-alertdialog

Im trying to make a dialog like the one shown in the screenshot below. Does anyone know how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should define a custom layout for the dialog and inflate it, the same as you do for activities. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) you can find a good example.

Answer (score 0):

In the DialogFragment's onCreateView() add:

```
     getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular [`AlertDialog.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html). Create a layout you want to show, inflate it, and call [`setView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) on the builder object. In your activity:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(view).show();
```